# Taking screenshot of a view gives black image?

Tags: android, screenshot

I tried to take a screenshot of a imageview programatically! When the image is saved to folder it is producing black image! when i tried to take screenshot of my entire scroll view, I am able to take screenshot. Please help:

my Code is:

```
private void saveop(){
        RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.opimagelayout);// which includes your view or buttons?
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(384,
                100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas bitmapHolder = new Canvas(bitmap);
        parent.draw(bitmapHolder);
        try {
            final File f = savebitmaps(bitmap,"operator","");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


public static File savebitmaps(Bitmap bmp,String transno, String currentDateandTime) throws IOException {
        Bitmap out = BITMAP_RESIZER(bmp, 384,112);
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MobeeLoad");
        File file = new File(folder, transno+".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fOut;
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            bmp.recycle();
            out.recycle();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        bmp.recycle();
        return file;
    }
```

Layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/opimagelayout"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:layout_height="90dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/opimage"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:src="@drawable/check"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_height="90dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check your bitmap before resizing to be sure that the drawing code really draws the layout to the bitmap. Then check the resizing code. You can pause execution and use 'evaluate expression' to get one of bitmap's pixels. Maybe there's anything in logcat's output?

Comment: You are compressing image , flushing it and then closing the file, I think that's the problem.